# Show that the function $f(\textbf{x}) =|\textbf{x}| $ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I can see this intuitively, but looking for a solid answer with reasoning.

all ideas will be appreciated,

Comment: The title isn't supposed to replace the first line of your question.

Answer (score 4):

$f(\mathbb x)=|\mathbf x|$ is the [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) of the space $\mathbb R^n$ so we can use the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)
$$
|\|\mathbf x\|-\|\mathbf y\||\le\|\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|
$$
to obtain
$$
|f(\mathbf x)-f(\mathbf y)|\le|\mathbf x-\mathbf y|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with $x=(x_1,...,x_n),y=(y_1...,y_n)$ and $|x-y|<\frac{\epsilon}{n}$,$\epsilon<1$. 

This means $|x_1-y_1|<\frac{\epsilon}{n}$,...,$|x_n-y_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{n}$. 

Then $||x|-|y||<|x-y|$ (triangle inequality), and $|x-y|=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...(x_n-y_n)^2}<\epsilon$. 

So we are done.